# Border color and background color become fuzzy on hover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I am working on some css styling. I have a css circle inside a bootstrap navbar. Everything looks nice and works fine.

However, on hover of the button, it looks like the border of the circle is becoming "fuzzy". Like this

[image]

it might be harder to see on this small image, but you can see the blue border becomes pixelated and blurry.

Does anyone know what's causing this? any help is much appreciated

**code**

the circle

```
span.circle-name {
  -moz-border-radius:50%;
  -webkit-border-radius:50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #5A9ADE;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #5A9ADE;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 14px;
  padding-right: 14px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

navbar button (less)

```
.navbar-user {
  .dropdown-toggle {
    color: #444444;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }

  .btn-group.open .btn.dropdown-toggle {
    background-color: #5B5B5B;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 0;
  }

  .btn-group .btn.dropdown-toggle:hover {
    background-color: #5B5B5B;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 0;

    .caret {
      border-top: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
    }
  }

  .btn-group > .dropdown-menu {
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    border-radius: 0;
  }

  @media (max-width: 767px) {
    .btn-group > .dropdown-menu {
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-left: -77px;
    }
  }

  .caret {
    border-top: 4px solid #444444;
  }

  .open .caret {
    border-top: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to post your code

Comment: @Johannes just did! :)

Comment: is that an image, the actual circle part? Or is this 100% CSS

Comment: @DannyV the grey background and blue circle are all CSS

Comment: We have not needed vendor prefixes for `border-radius` in many, many years.

Comment: @Rob i think that falls more under the _nitpick_ category than it does actually providing a constructive answer.

Comment: I made it as a note to you that you are using unnecessary, unused markup that browsers will ignore and haven't needed since Firefox 3 and Chrome 4. You can thank me later if you wish or point out that IE8 and lower still need it but you ignore them with what you have.

Comment: how about posting also the html code of that part?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the reason. When something is so small, it has a small resolution. When you make an ellipse, the pixels are becoming "boxy" (fuzzy) in order to create that curve. I would recommend make this logo into a PNG or something similar and just call it in as an `<img/>`

Comment: The `<img>` tag does not use or need a closing slash.

Comment: why shoud the pixels have a better/finer resolution in an image?

Comment: @Johannes this is from personal experience and the image tag does have the "/"

Comment: @DannyV I think this rather depends on the anti-aliasing capabilities of the OS / browser combination